# Share data between child components in Durandal

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs, require, durandal

I have created knockout application using Durandal and RequireJS and application has structure as shown below:

> - Student
>
>   - Students
>
>     - Manage
>
>       - index.js
>       - index.html
>     - index.js
>     - index.html
>   - Teachers
>
>     - Manage
>
>       - index.js
>       - index.html
>     - index.js
>     - index.html
>   - index.js
>   - index.html

As you can see in above diagram, **Students** and **Teachers** both are individual components and are children of the School.

[image]

Now I want to declare observable variable which can be shared between `Student/Manage/index.js` and `Teacher/Manage/index.js`.

One of the possible way is to declare a variable in `school/index.js` component and pass it to `teacher/manage/index.js` and `student/manage/index.js`. But I am not sure whether it is correct way or not. If not then what is the best practice to do it ?

Comment: I'm not a big fan of how Knockout handles components and child components, especially not for just passing some data. What I would do is creating some sort of 'school store' file where you add all the variables and observables you need. Then require/import the 'store' in the teacher and student files where you can subscribe on/mutate the variables/observables

Comment: @Skeevs : I believe that's a good suggestion.

Comment: As @Skeevs suggests. Just bear in mind the lifecycle of your store vs viewModels. If your school store is going to use observables for state then you'll need to make sure your viewModels dispose of any subscriptions they make. Durandal provides a `deactivate` method that you can use for cleanup http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Hooking-Lifecycle-Callbacks#combined-lifecycle
An alternative would be to use events to coordinate between viewModels http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Leveraging-Publish-Subscribe.html